# loadChildren syntax - what is hash part

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular [in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) says the following:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
},
```

I'm curious about the syntax. As I understand, this part:

```
app/admin/admin.module
```

defines the path to load a module. But what is this `#AdminModule`?

I'm reading [this article](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee#.tddkap3ws), and there is the following path:

```
loadChildren: 'contacts.bundle.js',
```

so, as you can see, there is nothing with hash.

Comment: @Pete, thanks, I think I've found [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41697514/2545680)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash part denotes the exported module name. So, inside `app/admin/admin.module` the `AdminModule` is exported:

```
export class AdminModule {}
```

However, if default export is used, there is no need to use hash.

Here is the relevant part from the sources `system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts`:

```
  private loadAndCompile(path: string): Promise<NgModuleFactory<any>> {
    let [module, exportName] = path.split(_SEPARATOR);
    if (exportName === undefined) exportName = 'default';

    return System.import(module)
        .then((module: any) => module[exportName])
        .then((type: any) => checkNotEmpty(type, module, exportName))
        .then((type: any) => this._compiler.compileModuleAsync(type));
  }
```